# Detect a blank webpage in WebView android

Tags: android, webview, html

I was wondering if there was a way to detect blank webpages using the webview.
Actually, this is a college app and so, it would not look appealing if the app loads a blank page and was thinking of using `WebView.loadURL("<html><body> <h1>Oops! We have an empty page here</h1></html>")` when I encounter a blank page.

So is there a way to implement this?

Btw. this is a case when the loaded URL webpage is empty and not a rendering issue or whatever it is called!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are two possible cases:**

1. Page does not load.
2. Page loads, but is blank.

**Solutions to each case:**

1. Attach a `WebViewClient` to your `WebView`, where you override `onReceivedError()` to find out more about the error.
2. Attach a `WebViewClient` to your `WebView` and in `onPageFinished()` use javascript to check how many child nodes `<body>` has. If it has no child nodes you can show your default html page.

To get number of child nodes you can use the `javascriptInterface` class like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: var count = document.body.childNodes; jsInterface.childCount(count.length);")
```